# iPhone crash log?

Tags: iphone, crash, logging

I have provisioned an iphone and had the user install the app. It fails.

Is there a crash log that I can see why it failed on the iphone?

Ian

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you can connect the iphone up to a computer with xcode, in the organizer window it shows the crash logs for each of the application's crashes.  Shortcut key in xcode to bring up the organizer Command+ctrl+o.

If they do not have access to xcode...

From http://www.anoshkin.net/blog/2008/09/09/iphone-crash-logs/

> Whenever you synchronize your iPhone or iPod Touch, all the crash logs are transferred to your computer. Here are their locations:
>   Mac OS X : ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/DEVICE_NAME
>   Windows XP: C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Application Data\Apple computer\Logs\CrashReporter/DEVICE_NAME
>   Windows Vista: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Apple computer\Logs\CrashReporter/MobileDevice/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use a crash reporting service to automatically send crash reports.  The best one I've found so far is Crittercism:

[www.crittercism.com](http://www.crittercism.com)