# iPhone crash logs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an app in ad-hoc mode and it crash right after starts. I have access to Xcode and i try to find crash log like here: [iPhone crash log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075990/iphone-crash-log)

But i have no crash log from this app. Why?

Right after app starts i can see *Default.png* and few second later it crash, i've never even see the mainViewController. How do get a crashlog? How to detect this error? I don't have an access to source code. I have only ad-hoc distribution.

Problem not occurs on every devices. AFAIK this is only 3GS problem. Strange.

Comment: I had once a similar problem because I compiled only for armv7. It crashed also only for 3GS and nearly every tester had a iPhone 4 (except the customer's CEO :-/)

Comment: But 3GS is armv7 architecture iPhone. The last one with armv6 was 3G and iPod Touch 2G.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looking for the crash log, try connecting your phone to xcode but look at the Console screen instead, run the app and you should see output on the console, see if you get an error message there.

For users who don't have access to Xcode or are running on a PC you can download Apple's iPhone Configuration Utility which also gives you access to the device console.